# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH error for minified Angular.js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, google-chrome

I am getting the following error on Google chrome browser

> **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH  error for minified Angular.js file**
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH /js/angular/angular.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined angular-cookies.js:6 
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined 
> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined  
> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

This error usually pops up when I delete browser's cache and try to access the application (Java/JSP application with angular.js for frontend).
But when I refresh the page the error goes away.

Also, in the browser source tab(Development tools), I find the angular.js file completely blank and in my server logs I don't see any error for my angular.js file request.

> **GET /*/js/angular/angular.js HTTP/1.1" 200 125539 3 1**

This issue sometimes also occur in Firefox

Has anybody experienced this issue and have any suggestions on how I can fix this issue?